# There is an API to integrate js (THREE) games with C++ minigames?

Tags: javascript, c++, threejs-editor

Im doing a game with Three, and i want to integrate an Opengl minigame in there, there is some api to do the between or i must to remake the minigame inside the js code?

Comment: Is your goal to *embed* an existing program into your application, and let it take over the display of your program (or possible render into a smaller canvas inside your application)?

Comment: Yes, like, i have made a minigame on c++ i want to, in certain point, display that minigame, but the game is made on three.js, and the minigame is a .cpp file (c++) ;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.